# pymysql error: 'str' object has no attribute 'nextset'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am running into an issue building a random project for myself. I am trying to record entries into a `mysql` database that the user types in. I am storing them in a dictionary. The error message is

```
  while self.nextset():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nextset'
```

I have googled and searched for this issue, but I only find issues kind of like it but not the same error.

My table headers in `mysql` db match the dictionary keys. I do realize I have issues with selection (2) but my error and what I am troubleshooting now is just when I select option (1).

```
import mysql
import pymysql
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

cursor = pymysql.cursors.Cursor

# Function for adding a new entry
def new_entry(name, date, task, time, notes):
    # Build dictionary with new entry information

    myDict = {
        'Employee': name,     # Name of employee
        'Date': date,         # Date of worked task
        'Task': task,   # Title of Task
        'Time': time,         # Time spent on task
        'Notes': notes   # Notes on the task
    }
    table = ('timesheet')
    placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(myDict))
    columns = ', '.join(myDict.keys())
    sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (table, columns, 
        placeholders)
    pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute(sql, myDict)

#list all entries for a particular employee
def previous_entries(emp_name):
    pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * from user_data WHERE Name = %s", (emp_name,))

#list all entries that match a date or search term
#def search_entries():
#    return null

#Print a report of this information to the screen, including the date, title 
#of task, time spent, employee, and general notes.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #cnx = mysql.connect(user='root', database='me10_mig')
    cnx = pymysql.connect(user='root', password='password', 
        database='me10_mig')

    print("Please enter (1), (2), or (3)")
    begin = input("Would you like to (1) enter a new entry or (2) display 
    all 
    previous entries or (3) display entries that match a date or search 
    term? ")

    if begin == '1':
        name = input("Your Name: ")
        date = input("Date of Time Worked: ")
        task = input("Title of Task: ")
        time = input("Time Spent on Task: ")
        notes = input("Notes on Time Worked: ")
        new_entry(name, date, task, time, notes)

    if begin == '2':
        name = input("What is the employee name: ")
        previous_entries(name)

    #if begin == '3':
```

The error I get says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a089673/Desktop/Python/TeamTreeHouse/Part 4/timesheet.py", line 61, in <module>
    new_entry(name, date, task, time, notes)
  File "C:/Users/a089673/Desktop/Python/TeamTreeHouse/Part 4/timesheet.py", line 27, in new_entry
    pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute(sql, myDict)
  File "C:\Users\a089673\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 165, in execute
    while self.nextset():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'nextset'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and add the full error stacktrace

Comment: If as user could paste code in without it messing up the indents that would be amazing!!

Comment: @YepramYeransian It indeed is possible. And easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your might stem from using a `dict` to hold the arguments to `.execute()`, but not using named string patterns in the SQL statement.

The [docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute) suggest using `%s` when passing a list or tuple, but rather use `%(name)s` when passing a `dict`.

I suggest you try this code:

```
def new_entry(name, date, task, time, notes):
    # Build dictionary with new entry information

    myDict = {
        'Employee': name,     # Name of employee
        'Date': date,         # Date of worked task
        'Task': task,   # Title of Task
        'Time': time,         # Time spent on task
        'Notes': notes   # Notes on the task
    }
    table = ('timesheet')

    column_list = []
    placeholder_list = []
    for k in myDict:
        column_list.append(k)
        placeholder_list.append('%(' + k + ')s')

    sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (
        table,
        ', '.join(column_list),
        ', '.join(placeholder_list))

    pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute(sql, myDict)
```

This will also ensure that the column names and the placeholders are in the same order. Your original code did not consider that (remember, iterating over dicts multimple time is not garanteed to give the same order each time).

---

I totally overlooked the part where you establish a connection to the database. You need to pass that connection as a parameter to `new_entry()` and use it.

Try this:

```
def new_entry(cnx, name, date, task, time, notes):
    sql = "INSERT INTO timesheet (Employee, Date, Task, Time, Notes) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    values = (name, date, task, time, notes)

    with cnx.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql, values)

cnx = pymysql.connect(user='root', password='password', database='me10_mig')
new_entry(cnx, ...)
```

Comment: for the Cursors.execute, what would the "args" be since it would no longer be "myDict"?  Something like Cursor.execute(sql, args)

Comment: My old one was pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute(sql, myDict)

Comment: I think it is myDict.values(),

Comment: That was not it, just gives the same error but I can try to build from here, thank you

Comment: @YepramYeransian no, the `.execute()` line could stay the same with these changes. I added it to my answer.

Comment: I am getting the same error. The "str object has no attribute 'nextset'. Is there another way to get around this. Maybe another method like not using a dictionary or something?

Comment: @YepramYeransian I edited my answer to include the connection part.